# Uninstalling Structure: preparations?

Tags: ee2, structure

I want to uninstall Structure on a site. The navigation rarely ever changes, so a dynamically generated menu isn't necessary; the people maintaining the site have some knowhow, and content is used in multiple places; and finally, I want to use EE's inbuilt Pages module but I don't know that I can with Structure installed.

Other than hardcoding the navigation, and then making sure to set all "static" pages as Pages, what else do I need to do, to uninstall Structure?

I'm running EE 2.5.3, Structure 3.3.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the native Pages module with Structure installed. You'll need to uninstall Structure before installing Pages.

I'd suggest making these change in a dev environment to CYA.

There shouldn't be anything more to do then uninstalling Structure, installing Pages, mapping URLs into Pages, setting up navigation, reworking anything in the templates as needed.

Comment: Yep - all being done in a dev environment, most definitely. Thank you for the information! (Structure is great...just not for our purposes. It does too much that isn't needed, and changes too much of the back-end workflow. Hence the need to uninstall.)